# Problem with JSON serialization in my database

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, entity

I am a mobile developer trying to set up his first Java Spring Boot API server. Everything works fine except when i try to make a post with my User entity in database. I have used @Embedded annotation and it seems its not working.

here is my User entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
@Data
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Embedded
    private Address address;

    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;

    @Column(name = "website")
    private String website;

    @Embedded
    private Company company;

}
```

Here is my Address class:

```
@Embeddable
public class Address {

    @Column(name = "street")
    private String street;

    @Column(name = "suite")
    private String suite;

    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "zipcode")
    private String zipcode;

    @Embedded
    private Geo geo;
}
```

Here is my Json body in postman :

```
{
  "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.tps",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
}
```

Here is a photo with my database element:
[My dataBase Line:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vj1T8.png)

I tried different addnotations, chat GPT advices and few other methods i found on the internet. The database Adrress elements doesnt seem to be updated.

Comment: Please also include the code for your controller, service, and DAO (or repository), such that folks can attempt to reproduce this